# Регулярные выражения Bash

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, awk

Возникла задача парсинга IP из строки в Bash скрипте. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
echo "1.1.1.1 asdsad" | awk '/((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)/{print $0}'
```

В ответ:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\d' is not a known regexp operator
```

Подскажите, что здесь не так? Как можно реализовать мою задачу иначе?

Comment: Бредовая идея описать все многообразие IP адресов регулярным выражением

Comment: `\d` - эквивалентно диапазону цифр `[0-9]`, попробуйте заменить в вашем выражении. Ну и `000.000.000.000` будет валидным для текущего выражения, причем не зависимо будут ли вначале дополнительные цифры или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `[0-9]` вместо `\d`, так как POSIX ERE не поддерживает второй шаблон.

```bsh
regex='((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})'
echo "1.1.1.1 asdsad" | \
 awk -v rx="$regex" 'match($0,rx){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

См. [пример работы скрипта онлайн](https://ideone.com/yG8XpQ).

Тут все `\d` заменены `[0-9]`, а `\d\d?` заменены `[0-9]{1,2}`.

С помощью `-v rx="$regex"` переменную с шаблоном IP-адреса можно передать в код программы `awk`, так легче работать с длинными шаблонами.

Кстати, ваш скрипт возвращает все *целые строки*, в которых было найдено совпадение. Чтобы найти и вернуть само совпадение с помощью `awk`, надо воспользоваться функцией `match`, которая ищет первое слева самое длинное совпадение и возваращает начальную позицию (индекс) найденной подстроки (`1` если совпадение найдено в начале строки). Если совпадение не найдено, возвращается нуль. Эта функция также устанавливает значения предварительно определенных переменных `RSTART` (начальная позиция совпадения) и `RLENGTH` (длина найденной подстроки). Если совпадение не найдено, `RSTART` равен нулю, а `RLENGTH` — `-1`. См. [документацию на англ. языке](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

раз в заголовке и среди меток присутствует название программы *bash*, я думаю, что решение средствами этой программы будет всё-таки «в тему»:

```
$ cat script
while read l; do
  for w in $l; do
    echo $w | while IFS='.' read n1 n2 n3 n4 o; do
      if [ -z "$o" -a \
        "$n1" -le 255 -a "$n1" -ge 0 -a \
        "$n2" -le 255 -a "$n2" -ge 0 -a  \
        "$n3" -le 255 -a "$n3" -ge 0 -a  \
        "$n4" -le 255 -a "$n4" -ge 0 ] 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "$n1.$n2.$n3.$n4"
      fi
    done
  done
done
```

```
$ cat testfile
1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4.5 bac
1.2.3,4 1.2.113.4 a.b.c.d
255.255.255.255 1.2.3.-4 4.5.6
255.255.255.256
```

```
$ cat testfile | bash script
1.2.3.4
1.2.113.4
255.255.255.255
```

впрочем, ничто не препятствует и тому, чтобы использовать как интерпретатор любую posix-совместимую оболочку. результат будет аналогичный:

```
$ cat testfile | sh script
1.2.3.4
1.2.113.4
255.255.255.255
```